# Как сделать текстовую игру с двумя игроками при помощи функции?

Tags: python

Как взывать эту функцию для второго игрока? С начало берёт первый, потом второй и т.д.. Долго сижу и думаю над решением, но так и не пойму как это сделать(

```
koloda = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 11] * 4
import random

random.shuffle(koloda)

print('Поиграем в очко?')


def player():
    count = 0
    while True:
        choice = input('Будете брать карту? y/n\n')
        if choice == 'y':
            current = koloda.pop()
            print('Вам попалась карта достоинством %d' % current)
            count += current
            if count > 21:
                print('Извините, но вы проиграли')
                break
            elif count == 21:
                print('Поздравляю, вы набрали 21!')
                break
            else:
                print('У вас %d очков.' % count)
        elif choice == 'n':
            print('У вас %d очков и вы закончили игру.' % count)
            break


player()

print('До новых встреч!')
```

Comment: Так добавьте в этот же цикл второго игрока.

Comment: тогда код дублируется

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

koloda = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 11] * 4
random.shuffle(koloda)

print('Поиграем в очко?')

def play():
    count = [0, 0]
    while True:
        for i in range(2):
            print('Игрок %d' % (i + 1))
            print('У вас %d очков' % count[i])
            choice = input('Будете брать карту? y/n\n')
            if choice == 'y':
               current = koloda.pop()
               print('Вам попалась карта достоинством %d' % current)
               count[i] += current
               print('У вас %d очков.' % count[i])
               if count[i] > 21:
                print('Извините, но вы проиграли')
                break
               elif count[i] == 21:
                print('Поздравляю, вы набрали 21!')
                break
            elif choice == 'n':
               print('У вас %d очков и вы закончили игру.' % count[i])
               break
               
                
play()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

koloda = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 11] * 4
random.shuffle(koloda)

print('Поиграем в очко?')


def play():
    players = ["y", "y"] # хранит последнее решение игроков брать/не брать
    count = [0, 0]
    round = 0 # использую чтобы понять какой игрок играет
    while players[0] == "y" or players[1] == "y":
        player = round % 2 # если 0 - играет первый, если 11 второй
        if player == 0 and players[0] == "n": # проверяем отказался ли брать игрок карту 
            round += 1
            continue
        if player == 1 and players[1] == "n": # проверяем отказался ли брать игрок карту 
            round += 1
            continue
        print()
        print('Игрок %d' % (round % 2 + 1))
        print('У вас %d очков' % count[player])
        choice = input('Будете брать карту? y/n\n')
        if choice == 'y':
            current = koloda.pop()
            print('Вам попалась карта достоинством %d' % current)
            count[player] += current
            print('У вас %d очков.' % count[player])
            if count[player] > 21:
                print('Извините, но вы проиграли')
                break
            elif count[player] == 21:
                print('Поздравляю, вы набрали 21!')
                break
        elif choice == 'n':
            if player == 0:
                players[0] = "n"
            elif player == 1:
                players[1] = "n"
        round += 1
# проверяем кто выйграл
    if count[0] > 21:
        print('Игрок 2 победил')
    elif count[1] > 21:
        print('Игрок 1 победил')
    elif count[0] > count[1]:
        print('Игрок 1 победил')
    elif count[0] < count[1]:
        print('Игрок 2 победил')
    elif count[0] == count[1]:
        print('Ничья')


play()
```